# Shell script for finding a file name using a string input

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, grep

Hi I'm starting to learn how make and use shell scripts, one the shell scripts I want to make is a shell script that takes in a string input from a user that is asking for a file name and it reports whether the file is present or not. I unsure of what to do.
Here's what I've written:

```
#!/bin/bash
read string1
 echo${#string1} ; grep
```

I don't know what to do after typing in grep.
Please help.

Comment: grep looks for a string that occurs in the file's contents. If you just want to test whether a file with a given name exists, grep is not necessary. `if test -e ${string1}; then echo The file ${string1} exists; fi` will do.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, add that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

grep looks for a string that occurs in the file's contents. If you just want to test whether a file with a given name exists, grep is not necessary.

```
#!/bin/bash
read string1    
if test -e ${string1}; then
    echo The file ${string1} exists
fi
```

will do.

[copied from comment to answer as suggested by @glenn jackman]

Comment: `-e` will test for existence of file (file being understood as directory, regular file, fifo, link, you-name-it). I think you should add this to your answer, to make it more comprehensive and really nice. Maybe add a few other tests, and why not excerpts of `help test`. Moreover, and since the question is clearly tagged [tag:bash], you could use the double square brackets `[[ ... ]]`. One more thing, **use more quotes**. Good luck `:)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the file test operator instead of grepping for the name:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Enter a filename: "
read string1

if [[ -f "$string1" ]]; then
    echo "The file '$string1' exists."
else
    echo "The file '$string1' does not exist!"
fi
```

Don't forget to quote your variables so that names with spaces and odd characters are parsed correctly.

```
$ bash test.sh 
Enter a filename: hash.pl
The file 'hash.pl' exists.

$ bash test.sh 
Enter a filename: odd file.txt
The file 'odd file.txt' exists.

$ bash test.sh 
Enter a filename: somefile
The file 'somefile' does not exist!
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the help, I appreciate you guys for the help!